# Pytorch how to stack tensor like for loop

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to concat tensor generated in for loop, and get 2dTensor.
standard python, like below.

```
li = []
for i in range(0, len(items)):
    # calc something
    li.append(calc_result)
```

In my case, in for loop, generate `torch.Size([768])` Tensor, and I want to get `torch.Size([len(item),768])` Tensor.
How to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html):

```
torch.stack(li, dim=0)
```

after the for loop will give you a `torch.Tensor` of that size.

Note that if you know in advance the size of the final tensor, you can allocate an empty tensor beforehand and fill it in the for loop:

```
x = torch.empty(size=(len(items), 768))
for i in range(len(items)):
    x[i] = calc_result
```

This is usually faster than doing the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is quite true, and just what I want.

Comment: I have a concern about grad functions chains! Does 'x' have 'calc_result' grad fn information?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer using `torch.stack` is incorrect because it inserts an additional dimension, giving a tensor of shape `[1, len(items), 768]`.

Use `torch.vstack` instead:

```py
torch.vstack(li, dim=0)
```

to get a tensor of shape `[len(items), 768]`.